# How do I select items from an array using an array of indices with Linq?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

How do I select items from an array using an array of indices with Linq?

Following code works:

```
String[] A = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
int[] idxs = new int[] { 1, 3 };
String[] B = new String[idxs.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < idxs.Length; i++)
{
     B[i] = A[idxs[i]];
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", B));
```

output:

```
        two, four
```

Is there a LINQ way (or other one-liner) to get rid of the for loop?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the for loop?  Is it slow? Hard to read?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use it with [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) your `index` and your `A[index]` Like:

```
String[] A = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
int[] idxs = new int[] { 1, 3 };
var result = idxs.Select(i => A[i]).ToArray();

foreach(var s in result)
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output will be:

```
two
four
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/Et8WCa).

Answer (score 16):

A LINQ way would be this:

```
var b = idxs.Select(x => A[x]).ToArray();
```